# How to skip table rows when exporting from PDF using camelot-py

Tags: python, python-camelot

I have the following table structure on each page in PDF:

| Small table header |
| --- |
| Small table text |
| Small table footer |

| Normal table header |
| --- |
| Normal table text |
| Normal table footer |

| Small table header |
| --- |
| Small table text |
| Small table footer |

I'd like to extract the *Normal table text* to Excel (preferably into one file).

I use the following code to do the export for all the tables (it creates a file for each page though):

```
#tables
tables=camelot.read_pdf("foo.pdf",flavor="stream", pages="1-3")
tables.export('foo.csv', f='csv')
#tables[1].to_excel("foo.xlsx")
```

By the way, `to_excel` is not working, it gives the following error:

> TypeError: NDFrame.to_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

How could I skip the unnecessary rows?
I could skip the tables but the documentation doesn't contain anything about how to read the lines. If I use the DataFrame format, I can't export from them.